# what method is created for this? perl

Tags: perl, methods, moose

I need an explanation of this one liner. Is this only calling the set() method? Or something else?

Thanks for the help!

`has 'shape' => 
( is => 'rw' );`

The object is using MooseX::FollowPBP.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic Moose syntax. `has` is a Moose keyword that defines an attribute in your class. The attributes name is *shape*, and it `is` `r`ead-`w`rite.

[It's](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Attributes.pod) [documented](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#has-$name%7C@$names-=%3E-%25options) [in](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute) [multiple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::MOP::Attribute) [places](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Cookbook/Basics/BinaryTree_AttributeFeatures.pod).

> `has $name|@$names => %options`
>
> This will install an attribute of a given `$name` into the current class. If the first parameter is an array reference, it will create an attribute for every `$name` in the list. The `%options` will be passed to the constructor for Moose::Meta::Attribute (which inherits from Class::MOP::Attribute), so the full documentation for the valid options can be found there.

The [MooseX::FollowPBP](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::FollowPBP) has nothing to do with it directly. It just changes the behavior of Moose, to turn the default accessor `$obj->shape` into `$obj->get_shape` and `$obj->set_shape`, following the suggestion of Damian Conway in his book *Perl Best Practices*.